# Yahoo! Merchant Checkout API Problems

Tags: python, xml, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm attempting to integrate with Yahoo!'s Checkout API for an existing Merchant account in a Django-based web app. I've already successfully been able to integrate their Catalog API, but for some reason I simply cannot get the Checkout API to work. I've crafted an XML request based on the example in their documentation, but it always simply returns a 10009 Auth Required error. I've confirmed that my partner account does, indeed have the correct authorization, and I just can't figure out why I would be getting this error. I don't believe that it's a malformed request, as I get the exact same result when I copy and paste their example request (changing the API token and such, obviously).

This is what my request looks like (with the store ID and token sanitized):

```
<ystorews:ystorewsRequest xmlns:ystorews="urn:yahoo:sbs:ystorews">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <StoreID>{storeid}</StoreID>
  <SecurityHeader>
        <PartnerStoreContractToken>{token}</PartnerStoreContractToken>
  </SecurityHeader>
  <Verb>create</Verb>
  <ResourceList>
    <CheckoutBasket>
      <ShoppingCart>
        <Item>
          <ID>foo</ID>
          <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </Item>
      </ShoppingCart>
    </CheckoutBasket>
  </ResourceList>
</ystorews:ystorewsRequest>
```

And this is the response that I get back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ystorewsResponse>
<ErrorMessages>
<Error>
<Code> 10009 </Code>
<Message> Auth Required </Message>
</Error>
</ErrorMessages>
</ystorewsResponse>
```

And this is what my Partner API Access looks like:
[image: Yahoo! Partner API Access]

Comment: It's doubtful that the XML would cause such an error. What does the code look like?

Comment: It's definitely not the code, I'm using the exact same code to submit the request with the Catalog API which works just fine. Whatever the problem is, it's to do with what I'm sending them. If I remove a tag, or cause it to be malformed I get back an error response telling me that I'm missing or have bad tags. I'm using the Requests library though, so the code looks like this: `response = requests.post(endpoint, data=request)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there were internal problems at Yahoo! that were preventing this from working. After I contacted their small business support team they were able to fix the problem and my code suddenly started working.

In case anyone else encounters similar problems, I found that the best way to get ahold of them was through their Twitter account: [@YSmallBizCare](http://twitter.com/YSmallBizCare).

Comment: I;m having the same weird authentication problems, their documentation and support section isn't much help.

Comment: I was getting the same error using the PHP code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753012/yahoo-store-order-api-access/15957640   I contacted Yahoo Small Business Customer Care by email and they said "We have made some adjustment in the backend."  Then the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here, but it's worth a shot.

You declare an XML namespace, but you don't use it at all. I suspect you wanted:

```
<ystorewsRequest xmlns="urn:yahoo:sbs:ystorews">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <StoreID>{storeid}</StoreID>
  <SecurityHeader>
        <PartnerStoreContractToken>{token}</PartnerStoreContractToken>
  </SecurityHeader>
  <Verb>create</Verb>
  <ResourceList>
    <CheckoutBasket>
      <ShoppingCart>
        <Item>
          <ID>foo</ID>
          <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        </Item>
      </ShoppingCart>
    </CheckoutBasket>
  </ResourceList>
</ystorewsRequest>
```

Note the lack of the ystorews namespace in the root element.

Comment: Sadly, that's not it. Initially I didn't have the namespace (it's not needed in the Catalog API), but when I could get the request to work I added it in to make it as consistent with their example request as possible. The request that I'm creating is literally exactly the same as their example except with my store id and token. :(

Comment: That is to say, when I COULDN'T get the request to work, I added in the namespace...